# How to locate a tableView which is added as a sub view to the child view of a view

Tags: swift, tableview, xctest, subview, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to automate a screen, where there is a cell, which, when tapped pops up a table view. Im using the Apples native framework, XCTest.

I want to assert elements in that tableview (it has subview injected into it), but I can not even see the tableview. I hav added accessibilityIdentifier, and I can see it as Other element, but when I try to get its children(descendents), it returns nothing.

Here is the screenshot:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnEDg.png)

I have added:

```
self.isAccessibilityElement = true
self.accessibilityIdentifier = "someSubview"
```

I have tried to record and see what that is going to do, it either crashes, or writes a code that is tapping some element that is on a main view, beneath the tableview that popped up on top of the main view.

The tableview has subview added to it:

```
tableView.addSubview(self.paymentTypeSelectorView)
```

In general, when I do:

```
po XCUIApplication()
```

- this command returns all the elements I can interact with. And there are no elements from that subview (tableview).
I have tried commands like:

```
po getApp()?.tables.otherElements["someSubview"].children(matching: .any)
```

Expected result: po XCUIApplication() will return all the elements on the screen including ones from the tableview(subview): Label1, Label2, Label3.

Actual result: Whatever I do, XCUIApplication returns the same output, without those elements in the tableview, as if those elements (those labels1,2,3) were not on the screen.

Anyone has experience with these kinds of stuff?
Im still not sure if I'm doing something wrong or it is limitation of the XCTest framework or simply implementation is done in automation-unfriendly way...

Comment: Which view did you set the accessibility identifier on? If it is the view containing the tableView, you will not be able to access the table.

Comment: Hey, exactly. ID is added to subview that is added to the tableView. For me, this is like a really fundamental thing, and its really odd that i can not access it in any way.  Thats why im pretty sure im doing something wrong here.

Comment: So it is: 
TableView -> PaymentSelectorView (here is ID I can see and select) -> Tableview -> cells

Comment: I've had this problem before, when you add a non-cell subview to a tableView you can't see anything inside that view. One of my colleagues asked Apple for technical support on it but we didn't get a solution... If UI testing it is essential then I'd suggest re-working your view hierarchy so that everything you want to access as a subview of a table view is also inside a cell, rather than a direct sub view of the table view. Sorry, I know that's not the solution you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks @Oletha, you have helped a lot.